# Update 30 fields in a table in one go

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update 2 columns in a table for 30 rows. Tried using dbms utility - arrays but it doesnt accept spaces. Please suggest an optimised way to update 30 rows in one go.

Comment: Can you show some code..or whatever you have tried !

Comment: You have to explain what you really want to do. Because what you wrote would be just an `UPDATE colum1 = value, colum2 = value WHERE column3 IN('val1', 'val2', ..., 'val30')`

Comment: 'in one go' means i dont want to write 30 separate update queries. i want to use loops or arrays that would do this job with one execution

Comment: You've been a member of StackOverflow for over two years, you've asked a number of questions, yet you've never accepted an answer and you've never answered a question.  I think it would be good for you to try contributing - I'm confident you know the answers to some questions and could make a positive contribution to this site.  And going back and accepting some answers would be the polite thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the definition of the "in one go", and what you are trying to set as the new value but the standard SQL update syntax for oracle should let you do what you want it to.

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET <column1_name> = <value1>, <column2_name> = <value2>
WHERE <column_name> = <value>
```

If you set the where clause so that it uniquely identifies the columns that you want to update, then this statement will update the columns for only those rows.  This could be as simple as WHERE  IN [, ].  If you have no way of uniquely identifying the rows you wish to update, then it becomes more difficult to do so, you may need subselects or temporary tables to store the keys of the records you need to update and run the update against the subselect.

http://psoug.org/reference/update.html might provide you with a bit more info.

The issues with spaces is a bit easier to answer, you will need to encapsulate your field names in an escape sequence, for example if the table name is A Table and the column name is A Column then you would use

```
Update "A Table"
Set "A Column" = <value>, "Another Column" = <value2>
Where <where_clause>
```

Comment: @killspice- I think this will result with an `ORA-01767`. Should either be `SET <column1_name> = <value>, <column2_name> = <value2>` or `SET (<column1_name>, <column2_name>) = select <value>, <value2> from dual`

Comment: @killspice - 'in one go' means i dont want to write 30 separate update queries. i want to use loops or arrays that would do this job with one execution

Comment: Thanks A.B.Cade - not really an oracle person, you are correct, it needs the ( ) around the set target.

Comment: @rohit, Without more info on the data you are trying to update it is difficult to provide more guidance, e.g. are you setting the same value for each of the 30 records, a value based on the current value in each record, or some other complex rule.  Similarly without further context on how you determine which 30 rows in the table (or is that all that's in the table) to update we can't provide more help in that area either.